# Rails multiple rating stars forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am currently working on a project to display questions with multiple options and each option has a display_type. (For example a question has 4 options all with the display_type: "stars") that should give a result like on this view:

[image]

displayed thanks to this code (haml) called in a loop with local answer_option and leading to the html following :

```
.match-form-item-stars
    #{answer_option.title}
    %fieldset{class:'rating'}
        - 5.downto(1).each do |i|
            = radio_button_tag answer_option.id, i
            = label(answer_option.id,i)
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating">
<input type="radio" name="34" id="34_5" value="5">
<label for="34_5">5</label>
<input type="radio" name="34" id="34_4" value="4">
<label for="34_4">4</label>
<input type="radio" name="34" id="34_3" value="3">
<label for="34_3">3</label>
<input type="radio" name="34" id="34_2" value="2">
<label for="34_2">2</label>
<input type="radio" name="34" id="34_1" value="1">
<label for="34_1">1</label>
</fieldset>
```

Like you can see on the html code, i can't get rid of the i value in the label which is not really fancy. I tried content: '' in css => not working. Tried
= label(answer_option.id,i,'') not working either.

Secondly, the values sent to the controller in the params are :"33"=>"4", "34"=>"2", "35"=>"5", "36"=>"2". That works! But i would like it to be encapsulated like that "star-answers": { "33"=>"4", "34"=>"2", "35"=>"5", "36"=>"2"}. I succeeded to do it if my options are displayed_type:checkbox with something like this:

```
= check_box_tag('answer_option[]',answer_option.id,id: answer_option.id)
%label{for: answer_option.id}
```

But this is different because i just needed to pass the id of checked option but not value...

Any idea of the change I should do to solve this two problems ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is that `formset` function?

Comment: Oh yeah, mybad on this, that should be fieldset html tag. No particular component here

Comment: I'm not sure what you are using to make the input star-shaped(ultimately it has to be css though), but whatever. Why don't you pass empty strings to the label method?

Comment: Re, yeah indeed that is only css and haml. If i delete the string in label, the stars stop working. Do you think i should change my css logic in order to pass empty string in label ?

Comment: Can't tell really without more code. You know, the reason open-source maintainers require/request "reproduction" of a bug from people is that, with reproducible code, it's almost always crystal clear what's wrong(or sometimes "it's a feature").

Comment: Yeah, to be honest i understood it when i saw no reply for it. I know this is a really specific problem depending on how i coded everything around. So no problem about that, i will try to figure it by myself. Thanks for your interest anyway.